# CSS for Making Email Opt-In Fit Mobile Devices

Tags: css, mobile-devices

I need help making the Email Opt-In bar under the Header look at the same on mobile devices as it does on my desktop. [Here is the website.](http://www.rachelfracassa.com/)

I am not skilled in any kind of coding so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Here is the CSS I am currently using:

```
/* this would be the color and size of the main bar */
#nsu-head {
    background-color: #ffcfde;
    padding: 34px;
}

/* basic text color and placement */
#nsu-head p {
    float: left;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* placement of the invitation text */
#nsu-head p.form_label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

#nsu-form-1 label {
    display: none;
}

/* hides the input field labels */
/* input button styling going for a circle with drop shadow */
input#nsu-submit-1 {
/* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
}

.type1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

/* controls the background color during inactive and hover states */
input#nsu-submit-1.nsu-submit {
    background: no-repeat darkMagenta;
    border: 1px solid darkMagenta;
}

input#nsu-submit-1.nsu-submit:hover {
    background: no-repeat black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/* placement of post sign up text if no thank-you page */
p#nsu-signed-up-1 {
    float: right;
    font-size: .9rem;
    color: #DDD;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top: -18px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is quite messy, but try doing this:

1) Look for Aweber's code. IN your source code looks like this

```
<div class="nsu-form" id="nsu-head">
<p class="form_label">Get <span style="font-style:italic;">Free</span> &nbsp;Tips to Be a Healthier Mama!</p>
<!-- Form by Newsletter Sign-Up v2.0.3 - http://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter-sign-up/ -->
<form class="nsu-form" id="nsu-form-0" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post"><p><label for="nsu-name-0"> </label><input class="nsu-field" id="nsu-name-0" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"  /></p><p><label for="nsu-email-0"> </label><input class="nsu-field" id="nsu-email-0" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required /></p><textarea name="nsu_robocop" style="display: none;"></textarea><p><input type="submit" id="nsu-submit-0" class="nsu-submit" name="nsu_submit" value="Get it!" /></p></form>
<!-- / Newsletter Sign-Up -->
</div>
```

it might be different in your Aweber's code, but you'll get the idea. Now, if your plugin allows it to, try to move this part:

```
<p class="form_label">Get <span style="font-style:italic;">Free</span> &nbsp;Tips to Be a Healthier Mama!</p>
```

outside `<div class="nsu-form" id="nsu-head">` (thus, that paragraph has to be BEFORE this nsu-form line)

Once you have this all, be sure to remove everything you currently have in your code and add it to header-left, like this:

```
<div id="header-left-section">
YOUR CODE HERE
</div><!-- #header-left-section -->
```

this will make your theme work as expected. That is: your form on the left and full width on mobile and your nav on the right and full width on mobile.

However, if you also want it to be full width in ANY screen, add this to your CSS:

```
#header-left-section, #header-right-section{float:none !important; clear:both; display:block}
```

This should fix every issue you have